# How to animate object hanging from a string using real Physics?

Tags: bezier-curves, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, svg

I'd like to animate this model so it acts like it's attached to a car mirror, with proper physics of course (swinging, and rotating enough to see both sides). I'd also like the top of the string to stay in place. The string is a bezier circle and the object is a svg mesh. I've been researching for a while and haven't found many good results.

I've seen this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEYaVEw9DpU) using a string simulated as a cloth with pins but the object that is pinned is not actually simulating real physics. Is that the only way currently possible? I would like to use real physics. How to go about animating this using real physics?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Create an active rigid body to serve as your mass. Create a passive rigid body which will not appear in the render, any shape.

1. first select the active, then the passive, then F3 rigid body connect. It will create an empty that already has a rigid body constraint on it.
2. Change the type of constraint to point.
3. drag the empty to where the point hinge should be.
4. Use a third active rigid body to apply the forces necessary to swing the pendulum.
5. Use a bezier circle as the string. Dissolve 2 of the verts and leave 2. Each vert should be hooked to a respective body.
6. See attached blend file.

[Rigid body on circle string point constraint blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SXAljxrm4UJWoWa3Q3ZbQ4sj5WCnpVXw/view?usp=sharing)

[image]