# Hanging an object from a string with physics

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, rigidbody, force-fields

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a Christmas ornament and it would be great if it could be as physically accurate as possible. It only has two elements, a disc with a small hole in the top, and a ribbon that goes through that hole.

What would be great in an ideal world is that the knot in the ribbon stays put, the disc hangs of the ribbon and the ribbon tightens as the disc falls. Then all of it was able to used with a rigid body set up so it could swing and spin.

Problem number one might be that the ribbon is too complex, it might be better off being being a simple strip of faces, with the knot as a separate piece.

I've tried with both cloth and rigid body though I don't know enough about rigid body to be able to make it work.

Does anyone have any ideas how it could be done? [image: Disc hanging from ribbon]

Comment: This question seems similar: [Object Hanging from String](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157933/how-to-animate-object-hanging-from-a-string-using-real-physics). You can use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCZ57BbXByM&ab_channel=Welcometocreativeworld) YouTube video for assistance